# How to replace PHP code in a file having newlinse

Tags: php, replace, file-get-contents, str-replace

I got some files to change by clicking a button. To go for it, i have the old string to replace, saved in database, and also the new one.
On the click button, it executes a function that is gonna find the old string in the PHP file, then gonna replace it by the new one. (Final goal is to automate the PHP edits in a web software after an update).

My problem is that it perfectly works on short strings (without newline), but as soon as there is a newline into the file, nothing happens.

This is my actual code :

```
    $path = '/mypath/' . $item['path'];
        $old_code = $item['old_code'];
        $new_code = $item['new_code'];
    }

    $pos = strpos(file_get_contents($path), $old_code);
    $file = file_get_contents($path);
    $str = str_replace($old_code, $new_code, $file);
    file_put_contents($path, $str);
```

$pos is "true" if my $old_code doesn't have any newline.
I tried to use preg_match to remove \n, but the problem is that when i'll have to push my edits on the file with file_put_contents, every newline will also disapear.

Example of non-working str_replace :

```
echo "ok";     echo 'hey there is some spaces before'
echo 'this is a sentence';
$menu = ['test1', 'test200'];
print_r($menu);
$url = "/link/to/test";
$div = "echo \"<div class='central_container' align='center'>\";";
```

Do you have any idea for resolving this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if I`m not wrong str_replace() work only with single lines . Its have 2 options.
Option line replace str_replace() with preg_replace() or just use https://regex101.com/ there also have code generator after you finish you Regex

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try to use regex to know if there is a newline.